# Why am I getting a list object is not callable error on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I am working on this dataset [https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Reuter_50_50] and trying to analyze text features.

I read the files and store it as follows in the documents variable:

```
documents=author_labels(raw_data_dir)
documents.to_csv(documents_filename,index_label="document_id")
documents=pd.read_csv(documents_filename,index_col="document_id")
documents.head()
```

Subsequently, I am trying to generate tf-idf vectors using sublinear growth and storing it in a variable called vectorizer.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input="filename",tokenizer=tokenizer,stop_words=stopwords_C50)
```

Then, I try to generate a matrix, X, of `tfidf` representations for each document in the corpus, using:

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents["filename"])
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-8c01204baf0e> in <module>
----> 1 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents["filename"])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1611         """
   1612         self._check_params()
-> 1613         X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1614         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1615         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1029 
   1030         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1031                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1032 
   1033         if self.binary:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    941         for doc in raw_documents:
    942             feature_counter = {}
--> 943             for feature in analyze(doc):
    944                 try:
    945                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    327                                                tokenize)
    328             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 329                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    330 
    331         else:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you post the complete error output?

Comment: sure, I have added it now

Comment: You might need to pass an element of documents["filename"] to fit_transform() and not the whole thing. This is just a guess though, I don't know for sure.

Comment: @andole I tried doing that too, but I get this error instead: `ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.`

Comment: Then it must be 'documents' what is typed incorrectly. I'm afraid that's all of the help I can give you.

Comment: @andole alright, I'll look into this. And, thank you for your help! Have a good weekend :D

Comment: Could you post the output from `document.head()`??

Comment: This is the output:

`filename label  document_id  
0 ../../raw/C50/C50train/AaronPressman/106247new... AaronPressman
1 ../../raw/C50/C50train/AaronPressman/120600new... AaronPressman
2 ../../raw/C50/C50train/AaronPressman/120683new... AaronPressman
3 ../../raw/C50/C50train/AaronPressman/136958new... AaronPressman
4 ../../raw/C50/C50train/AaronPressman/137498new... AaronPressman
`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured out the answer to my own problem.

If I drop all the parameters in `vectorizer`, such that:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
```

The code runs just fine. Then, I added the input parameter back, and it still worked fine.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input="filename")
```

Ditto if I add the stop words back:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input="filename",stop_words=stopwords_C50)
```

However, when I pass tokenizer, it throws up an error.

As it turned out, the argument which I was passing to the `vectorizer` was a list of tokens, when it should have been another function.

I defined a function `stem_tokenizer` as follows:

```
def stem_tokenizer(text):
    return [porter_stemmer.stem(token) for token in word_tokenize(text.lower())]
```

And, passed this to `vectorizer`:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input="filename",tokenizer = stem_tokenizer, stop_words=stopwords_C50)
```

This resolved the issue for me.